# Disable UDP Flood protection on specific port

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm running openconnect's ocserv on Ubuntu 18.
It is running and i can connect to it but connection speed, specifically upload speed is low and most of the times connection drops after some time randomly. note that i have UFW installed and with UFW turned off, i do not have this problem.
My question is this:
How can i disable UDP Flood protection on my openconnect server port?